# Toggling autostart Android

Tags: android

trying to create a app that will autostart on boot, but with an option to turn this function off. Very new to programming.

this is in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

this is the listener class

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean auto = prefs.getBoolean("as", true);

    if(auto == true) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

this is the settings class

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    autostart= (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    autostart.setOnClickListener(this);

    settings = getSharedPreferences("as", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean auto = prefs.getBoolean("as", false);

    if(auto == true){
        autostart.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        autostart.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Switch auto = (Switch) view;
    if (auto.isChecked())
    {
        editor.putBoolean("as",true);
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "autostart on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editor.commit();

    }else{
        editor.putBoolean("as",false);
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "autostart off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to use a button to toggle the autostart function, i get no errors, but as is the program always starts on boot. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use an onCheckedChangedListener instead of onClick

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value to different preferences than you try to read it from. You are using `getSharedPreferences("as")` to store it and `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` to read it.

Also, [prefer using package manager to enable or disable the broadcast receiver itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409983/4538344).